# Jquery checkbox problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my check boxes

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="red" width="100%" >
<tr><td width="50%"><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkAll" value="0" >All</TD><TD><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkBuyer" value="1">Buyer/Importer</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkSeller" value="2">Seller/Exporter/Manufacturer</TD><TD><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkService" value="3">Service Provider</td></tr>                          
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkDistributor" value="4">Distributor</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkSupplier" value="5">Supplier</TD></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="businessTypeGroup" id="chkTrading" value="6">Trading Company&nbsp;<span id="businessTypeGroupError"></td></tr>
</table>
```

As per this code one senario is not working 
1] try to check other checkboxes not able to check All

```
$("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").click (function(){
$("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").click (function(){
var totalCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").length;         
var checkedCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']:checked").length;
    if ( totalCheckboxes === checkedCheckboxes ){               
        $("#chkAll").attr("checked" , true );   
    }else{
        $("#chkAll").attr("checked" , false );
    }   
   });
 });

 $("#chkAll").click ( function(){
   $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").attr ( "checked" , $(this).attr("checked") );  
});
```

Comment: you are having some typo - closing brace missing in the click-assignment

Comment: It is because I have altered your HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use ids for the checkboxes and then use the above method since `#` is an id selector.

or you can use

```
$(function(){
    $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").click (function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

See [attributeEquals selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)

***Edited***

```
$(function(){
    $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").click (function(){
        $("#chkAll").attr ( "checked" , false );
});

$("#chkAll").click ( function(){
    $("input:checkbox[name='businessTypeGroup']").attr ( "checked" , $(this).attr ( "checked" ) );  
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" value="0" >All
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBuyer" name="businessTypeGroup"  value="1" >Buyer/Importer
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSp" name="businessTypeGroup"  value="2" >Service Provider
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSupp" name="businessTypeGroup"  value="3" >Supplier
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/oyoxe)**

**[Another demo](http://jsbin.com/ipeqe)**

This will check the checkbox All when all other checkboxes are checked. And if any one is unchecked then checkbox All will be unchecked.

Comment: Remember to leave the name attribute so that the values is posted. (I am not complete sure, that this is necessary, but it's certainly a practice to always specify the name of an input type="checkbox".)

Comment: Still there is problem when i try to uncheck the All checkbox. its not working properly

Comment: My actual requirement is 
1] When i check All it will check all check boxes.
2] When i uncheck All it will uncheck all check boxes.
3] When All is checked and uncheck any other it will uncheck All check box.

Comment: In Demo when i try to check below  check box it should check All also
Buyer/Importer
Service Provider
Supplier